# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined on useState value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react, I'm getting this error constantly and after google some I can't find the reason why the useState value can't be read as array :( ... this the error I'm getting: *'TypeError: team.map is not a function'*

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

    const SportTeams = () => {
      const [team, setTeam] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        const getSports = async () => {
          const response = await fetch("https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/all_sports.php");
          const data = await response.json();
          setTeam(data);
          console.log(data);
        }
        getSports();
      }, []);

      return (
        <div className="myClass">
          <ul>
            {team.map((sport, index) => {
              return <li key={`${sport.strSport}-${index}`}>{sport.strSport}</li>
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default SportTeams;
```

Comment: becausue you map it before it fetches the data from api you can solve it like: `{team.length > 0 && team.map((sport, index) => {
              return <li key={`${sport.strSport}-${index}`}>{sport.strSport}</li>
            })}`

Comment: the value returned from the request isn't an array.

Answer (score 1):

Just update `setTeam` like following, your error will be resolved.

```
setTeam(data.sports);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are setting the team state with the data without checking if its undefined. If the data is undefined your state team become undefined as well. So make sure to check the data.

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

        const SportTeams = () => {
          const [team, setTeam] = useState([]);

          useEffect(() => {
            const getSports = async () => {
              const response = await fetch("https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/all_sports.php");
              if (response) {
                const data = await response.json();
                if (data) {
                  setTeam(data);
                }
              }
              console.log(data);
            }
            getSports();
          }, []);

          return (
            <div className="myClass">
              <ul>
                {team.map((sport, index) => {
                  return <li key={`${sport.strSport}-${index}`}>{sport.strSport}</li>
                })}
              </ul>
            </div>
          );
        };
        export default SportTeams;
```

There might also be the chance that your response is not what you expected and the actual data might be inside your response. In that case you need check what your response first then proceed to set the data.

Comment: Have you checked your response? As Mukarram Javid mentioned below. looks like your data is not an array instead data.sports is the array you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment. the value you are setting to teams isn't an array.

[image]

```
const data = await response.json();
setTeam(data.sports);
```